# Using django-rest-elasticsearch

Tags: django, elasticsearch

Following this [documentation](http://django-rest-elasticsearch.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), I have managed to get an API endpoint that gets data from elasticsearch. My problem is that the data fetched comes from all the `types` in an index whereas I would like to get the data from one specific `type` from the index

Answer (score 0):

I'm not using `django-rest-elasticsearch`. Instead I use `elasticsearch` and `elasticsearch_dsl` packages. In that, what I do is something like

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from elasticsearch_dsl import Search

client = Elasticsearch(ES_ENDPOINTS)
s = Search(using=client, index='my_index', type='my_type')
s = s.query("match_all")
s.execute()
```

Hope it helps you